# Seven months pregnancy

Tags: medicine, pregnancy-birth, masechet-yevamot

There are places where it mentions a seven month full term pregnancy such as the [Mishna Yevamos 100a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9759&st=&pgnum=209). In modern day science is there such a concept as a seven month pregnancy that is considered full term? Is this a case of Nishtanu HaTeva?

Comment: Is this a question on Judaism or modern science?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about science (biology?)

Comment: @Scimonster - IMO - This is on topic.  It's not about science, but about reconciling rabbinic thought with reality.  It's very similar to the "Do sheidim exist?" type questions.

Comment: @Yishai Not a duplicate, but very similar.  They can use similar sources for answers, but the selected answer there glosses over the question here.  That one is "What are Chaza"l saying?" and this one is "How does what Chaza"l said square with modern reality?"

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I could see a distinction in that that question focuses on the 8 month baby question, and this one focuses on the 7 month baby, but I do wonder if this question needs better clarity about how it is distinct from the other one. I think that one isn't simply "what are Chaza"l saying" but also has a component of "how do I relate to such beliefs when science contradicts it".

Comment: @Scimonster, it's a question about modern science ["as it relates directly to Judaism"](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1474), I think.

Comment: Ok, Gershon - Care to weigh in?  How does this question differ from the suggested dupe?  What's this adding uniquely? cc: @Yishai

Comment: @Yishai: I am OK with the question being closed. Had I seen that question I would not have asked mine.